# Using Lodash `_.get` to access object key using bracket notation

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following

```
const key = 'foo';
const test = { foo: { bar: 23 } };
```

and I'd like to use lodash `get` to access the value of `test[key].bar`.

I want to use the bracket notation on the first indicator...

```
_.get(test, '[key].bar'); // results in undefined
```

Surely there's a way...

Comment: Your first example doesn't work for me. I doubt lodash uses eval here.

Comment: thanks @scimonster.  I thought i had tested that, but i also see it not working now...will remove

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can pass an array to define the evaluation path.

This is one pretty clean solution to your problem:

```js
const test = {foo: {bar: 23}}
const key = 'foo'

console.log(_.get(test, [key, 'bar'])) // 23
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to put the *value* of `key` into your path string:

```
_.get(test, key + '.bar');
```

In ES2015 you can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (interpolated string):

```
_.get(test, `${key}.bar`);
```

Comment: What if `key` isn't a legal identifier?

Comment: @Scimonster If I understand the question, that isn't a problem: http://jsbin.com/xuyiyiroto/edit?html,js,console

Comment: It is a problem if the key contains a dot

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = { foo: { bar: 23 } };
const key = 'foo';
const search = key + '.bar';

const result = _get(test, search);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal which uses a global variable, when enclosed in brackets.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path.replace(/(?=\[)/g, '.').split('.').reduce(function (o, k) {
        var m = k.match(/^\[([^\]]*)\]$/);
        return m ? (o || {})[window[m[1]]] : (o || {})[k];
    }, object);
}

var test = { foo: { bar: 23 } },
    key = 'bar';

console.log(getValue(test, 'foo[key]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse JSON before get
`JSON.parse(<YOUR JSON String or Obj>)`

```
const test = { foo: { bar: 23 } };
const key = 'foo';


const result = _get(JSON.parse(test), key );
```